# Bot get and save user message image then send it random on discord

Tags: python, discord

Is there any ways that I make my bot get the image in message and send it random

I tried this:

```
import random
@bot.command()
async def upload(ctx):
    up_img = ctx.attachments[0].url


@bot.command()
async def send(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    await channel.send(random.choice(file=up_img))
```

But it didnt work

Can anyone help me, I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue in the `send` command. You need to use a `TextChannel` object rather than just the **channel name**.

---

**To fix this issue**, you should replace the line `channel = ctx.channel.name` with `channel = ctx.channel`.

```
@bot.command()
async def send(ctx):
    channel = ctx.channel  # Use the TextChannel object instead of the channel name
    if uploaded_images:
        image_url = random.choice(uploaded_images)
        await channel.send(image_url)
    else:
        await ctx.send("No images uploaded yet.")
```

---

Keep in mind to replace "token" in `bot.run("token")` with your **actual Discord bot token.**

Comment: oh 1 more thing, if i want change all this to slash command do I need to change all the code or just add some code

Comment: What do you mean by slash command?

Comment: like my prefix now just: "$" so i need to write exactly in the message to use command. I see another bot only use '/' and then all the command show up, they don't need to remember all the command

Comment: You can just modify `command_prefix`.

Comment: can you show me example 1 command sir.Thank you so much

Comment: I have try `bot.slash_command` and `bot.tree.command` but none of them work

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, it looks like that i didn't understand your question properly. However to match your requirements i think, you'll need to store the URLs of the uploaded images somewhere so that you can access them later.

```
import random

uploaded_images = []

@bot.command()
async def upload(ctx):
    up_img = ctx.message.attachments[0].url
    uploaded_images.append(up_img)
    await ctx.send("Image uploaded successfully.")

@bot.command()
async def send(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    if uploaded_images:
        image_url = random.choice(uploaded_images)
        await channel.send(image_url)
    else:
        await ctx.send("No images uploaded yet.")

@bot.command()
async def clear(ctx):
    uploaded_images.clear()
    await ctx.send("Uploaded images cleared.")
```

- list called `uploaded_images` stores the URLs of uploaded images.
- **`upload`** command, appends the URL of the uploaded image to the `uploaded_images` list
- **`send`** command, checks if there are any uploaded images in the `uploaded_images` list.
- **`clear`** command clears the `uploaded_images` list.

**Referring to your further questions:**

To get a `discord.TextChannel`, you can use the `discord.utils.get` function or directly mention the channel in the command. Example:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.command()
async def send(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    # Code to send a message to the specified channel
    await channel.send("Hello, channel!")
```

---

If you want to upload **multiple images** and **send one random image** to the channel, you can modify the `upload` command to accept multiple attachments. Updated code:

```
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

uploaded_images = []

@bot.command()
async def upload(ctx):
    if len(ctx.message.attachments) > 0:
        for attachment in ctx.message.attachments:
            uploaded_images.append(attachment.url)
        await ctx.send("Images uploaded successfully.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("No images attached.")

@bot.command()
async def send(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    if uploaded_images:
        image_url = random.choice(uploaded_images)
        await channel.send(image_url)
    else:
        await ctx.send("No images uploaded yet.")

@bot.command()
async def clear(ctx):
    uploaded_images.clear()
    await ctx.send("Uploaded images cleared.")
```

- With this updated `upload` command, you can attach **multiple images** when invoking the command.
- The **URLs of the uploaded images** are stored in the `uploaded_images` list, and you can later use the send command to send a **random image URL** to the **specified channel**.

---

To retrieve the **channel `ID`** of the channel from which the user sent the command, you can use `ctx.channel.id` in your command. Try to use this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.command()
async def get_channel_id(ctx):
    channel_id = ctx.channel.id
    await ctx.send(f"The ID of this channel is: {channel_id}")
```

The get_channel_id command **retrieves the `ID`** of the channel from which the command was sent using `ctx.channel.id`. It then sends a message back to the same channel with the channel ID.

You can replace the `ctx.channel.id` with the desired variable or parameter in your code to get the **channel ID** of the user's channel and use it as needed.

---

The error message suggests that you're trying to use the `send` method on a string object (`image_url`) instead of a `discord.TextChannel` object.

You can resolve it by checking if `channel` is a valid `discord.TextChannel` object.

Modification of `send` command:

```
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

uploaded_images = []

@bot.command()
async def upload(ctx):
    if len(ctx.message.attachments) > 0:
        for attachment in ctx.message.attachments:
            uploaded_images.append(attachment.url)
        await ctx.send("Images uploaded successfully.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("No images attached.")

@bot.command()
async def send(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    if uploaded_images:
        image_url = random.choice(uploaded_images)
        await channel.send(image_url)
    else:
        await ctx.send("No images uploaded yet.")

@bot.command()
async def clear(ctx):
    uploaded_images.clear()
    await ctx.send("Uploaded images cleared.")
```

Also make sure that youre passing a valid `discord.TextChannel` object as the argument when invoking the send command.

---

To create a **line break** or **insert a new line** in your messages, you can use the newline character `\n`.

Example of such a function:

```
@bot.command()
async def example(ctx):
    message = "Hello, this is the first line.\nThis is the second line.\nAnd this is the third line."
    await ctx.send(message)
```

---

Please let me know if it soled your problem, and if so, then please **leave your opinions**. If your problem was solved, please mark my answer as a accepted answer :). ^^

Comment: They meant sending a random image uploaded earlier, not sending the recieved image to a random server.

Comment: uh I have 2 questions sir
1. Can you teach me how to get discord.text channel
2. The upload command, can we upload 10 or more image and it still random send 1 each in channel?

Comment: og you really save my life
but I have another issue sorry sir:)
in the `async def send`
when I ran the project it said:
`File "D:\DiscordPY-Bot-Tutorial-master\main1.py", line 73, in send
    await channel.send(image_url)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send'`
````````````````````````````````````````````````
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send'`
btw can I ask how to break line in here it very annoying when words stick together

Comment: can you check out my code it still have problem, thank you so much
https://github.com/Namg1/discordbot2023/tree/main